# Linq to SQL: Sum with multiple columns select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to convert the following SQL code into linq to sql but can't seem to find a way

```
select holder_name,agent_code,sum(total) 
from agent_commission
group by agent_code
```

Can anyone help me? Am kinda stuck with this for quite a while.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
I tried the following

```
var query = (from p in context.Agent_Commissions
               group p by new
               {
                     p.agent_code
               }
               into s
               select new
               {
                    amount = s.Sum(q => q.total),
                }
              );
```

How do I select the other two columns? What am I missing?

Comment: This question is on .net code for linq-to-sql, how come that it belongs to server fault?

Comment: `from a in ctx.agent_code
 group a by a.holder_name, a.code into totals
 select { holder_name = a.holder_name, code = a.code, total = totals} `

Comment: @vittore sorry for the typo in tag...

Comment: @vittore am not sure what your code does... i don't seem to see the sum part...

Answer (score 3):

In fact your `SQL query` **works only** when the corresponding relationship between `holder_name` and `agent_code` is `1-1`, otherwise the `Group by agent_code` won't work. So your `linq query` should be like this:

```
var query =  from p in context.Agent_Commissions
             group p by p.agent_code into s
             select new {
                holder_name = s.FirstOrDefault().holder_name,
                agent_code = s.Key,
                amount = s.Sum(q => q.total)
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your linq query

```
from a in ctx.agent_code 
group a by a.holder_name, a.code into totals 
select { holder_name = a.holder_name, 
         code = a.code, 
         total = totals.Sum(t=>t.total)}
```

Given that you have linq2sql context in `ctx` variable and it has your table in it.

Comment: Sorry it does not solve my problem. I only need to group by agent_code but display the holder_name,agent_code and sum(total)

Comment: where holder_name comes from ? you original sql statement is not valid if you are not putting holder name into group together with code